# Assign Public IP on Private LAN

Tags: networking, router

I have 5 reserved (unused) public addresses that I purchased (/29) from my ISP, and I'd like to assign one of those addresses to a Windows server/client machine that exists in my private LAN.

The purpose is from anywhere I want to access the server/client machine **without port forwarding** in my **MikroTik Router**.

Is it possible to do this? If the answer is yes, then how?

Comment: You cannot assign an outside public address inside your LAN to access the LAN remotely. Install a VPN router and access it via VPN.  This works great - I have done it.

Comment: You may be able to assign the public IP address to your internal server by using Proxy Arp on your router. I haven't implemented a solution using this in over 15 years so I cannot remember the specifics but I have seen it, had it working

Comment: Yeah, probably the solution would be Proxy ARP, 1-to-1 NAT, or by some means move the LAN host to the WAN (by adjusting the VLAN configurations or so), *if* your router has such flexibility / capability.

Comment: It depends! Does your ISP offer documentation on how this subnet is supposed to be used? What’s your access technology? DSL, Cable, Fiber, …?

Comment: @DanielB Usually, the ISP routes static IPs you purchased to your connection / edge router, is there anything else that determines how you use them? Why is the access technology relevant for IP routing?

Comment: @DanielB ISP didn't provide documentation, It is normal for where I have live in. They just provide me a 8 block IP segment. There is 5 IP I have left to use, I can assign this IP to my MikroTik ether interface for getting Internet connection. They provide it via Fiber optic cable.

Comment: @John It's not outside Public address, I have purchased from ISP. I can use any of them on my router interface for connected to the internet.

Comment: @ChrisDavies Can you provide me the step by step guide?

Comment: @YeasirArafat, sorry, no I can't - "_I haven't implemented a solution using this in over 15 years so I cannot remember the specifics_". That's why I've not posted this as an answer - it isn't one

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, there are loads of examples on the internet, [text-based](https://www.premitel.uk/consultancy/expert-advice/how-to-assign-public-ip-subnet-on-mikrotik-router-without-nat/) as well as [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=H4uaO8nDE4Q) for MikroTik routers.

Please note that assigning public IP addresses (and routing them) to a machine in your private network makes this machine (which is inside your private network) a "public machine". There are potential security issues here if you don't address the risks involved with this configuration.

Here's an example ([source](https://www.premitel.uk/consultancy/expert-advice/how-to-assign-public-ip-subnet-on-mikrotik-router-without-nat/)):

**Step 1**: Assign IP Addresses to Mikrotik Interface to which your device will be connected.

```
This could be Bridge, LAN or VLAN depending on your particular set up.

In my case I required my VoIP phone to be on VLAN 100.

You also need to decide what IP address is to be assigned to your interface and what addresses are to be used for your device(s).

In my case 87.XXX.YYY.229 was assigned to the interface with 87.XXX.YYY.230  assigned to the VoIP phone.

The Mikrotik script for achieving this is:

/ip address

add address=87.XXX.YYY.229/30 interface=vlan1000 network=87.XXX.YYY.228

The /30 subnet mask is essential as I discovered after some trial and error.

This script automatically creates an IP route as follows:

    Dst Address – 87.XXX.YYY.228/30
    Gateway – vlan 100 reachable
    Pref Source – 87.XXX.YYY.229
```

**Step 2**: Create Firewall Rule to Allow Connections from Subnet

```
You will probably have a firewall rule that allows connections from your private subnets to the internet and drops everything else.

You will therefore need to create a rule to allow connections from your public subnet.

This is the script that I used:

/ip firewall filter

add action=accept chain=forward connection-state=new out-interface=ether1 src-address=87.XXX.YYY.228/30

My WAN interface is ether1.
```

**Step 3**: Assign IP Address to Device

```
To assign the chosen public IP address(es) to your device you have the option of manually configuring the network settings in your device or you can configure your Mikrotik router to assign the address(es) by DHCP.

To assign the IP address manually you would enter the device IP (87.XXX.YYY.230), gateway IP (87.XXX.YYY.229) and DNS server (eg 8.8.8.8) information into the device’s network settings.

To configure your Mikrotik router to assign the IP address by DHCP you would use the following scripts:

/ip pool

add name=pool_100 ranges=87.XXX.YYY.230

/ip dhcp-server

add address-pool=pool_100 authoritative=after-2sec-delay disabled=no interface=vlan100 name=dhcp_100

/ip dhcp-server network

add address=87.XXX.YYY.228/30  dns-server=8.8.8.8 gateway=87.XXX.YYY.229

If you had a large subnet you would increase the DHCP Pool range accordingly.
```

**Step 4**: Create Firewall Rule to Allow Connections to Subnet

```
You may want to allow connections from the outside world to one or more devices that have been assigned IP addresses in your public subnet.

This may be from specific external public IP addresses or it may be from all public IP addresses if your subnet device (eg a router) has its own firewall.

You will therefore need to create a rule to allow external connections to your public subnet.

This is the script that I used:

/ip firewall filter

add action=accept chain=forward dst-address=87.XXX.YYY.228/30 in-interface=ether1

The above script allows all external connections to all addresses in the public subnet, but this can be restricted to specific external IP addresses using the “src-address” field or specific subnet addresses in the “dst-address” field.

You may need one or more additional lines in the firewall filter to achieve the restrictions that are required.
```

I don't have a MikroTik Router so unfortunately I can not test this.

Comment: The poster asked for a solution that doesn't involve port-forwarding or other parameters of the MikroTik router, while your answer does just that.

Comment: I might be blind, but where do you see a port forward?

Comment: I said "port-forwarding or **other parameters**".

Comment: I can see the addition about "port-forwarding" in the question, but nothing about "other parameters". What specific "other parameter" in my answer do you see as problematic and why? Outlining the relevant and irrelevant parts of your comment would help to avoid those misunderstandings in the future.

Comment: Look, you're suggesting to modify inside the router, which the poster asked to avoid. I think we discussed the subject enough.

Comment: The OP only asks to avoid "port-forwarding", there is nothing about "not involving other parameters" or "not modify inside the router". Maybe you just misunderstood the question. But if you have any insight others don't it would be nice of you to share.

Comment: Thank you for trying to providing a solution. But this one is complex method for me. I can't connect the device directly to another interface on my MikroTik Router. The Devices I want to assign Public IP they already on may private LAN.

Comment: @YeasirArafat the device doesn't need to be connected "directly" to your router. But you will need to specify which interface/port will serve this specific public IP address or range. Unfortunately no way around that, that's just how routing works. If you don't want to do that your only option is to do port forwarding. How exactly are you planning to connect your device to the router? Please provide a network schematic in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you won't be able to pass IP address from your WAN side to your LAN side. The only way to achieve this will be the following options:

Option 1:This is the best option and no other configuraiton is required
you create 2 bridges:

1- Bridge-WAN: Any interface which is the member of this bridge will route the IP address. The issue with this option is you need to connect your server or customer's router directly to the port which is member of bridge-WAN and not through your switch trunk port.

2- Bridde-LAN: Any port or VLAN assigned to this bridge will be you LAN side and will be pass through your switch trunk port.

Option 2: for this option you need 2 subnets which will be provided by the ISP
let's say you get /30 for your router and /29 or in my case I have /27 for internal usage.
When the ISP provide these 2 subnets the second one which they call it your LAN can be route to either Bridge-LAN or Bridge-WAN just like any of your internal IP address.
The only difference here is that ISP route the whole 2nd subnet over the first subnet therefor it doesn't matter weather they come from WAN port or from LAN port, both are routable.

I hope this help